# Cleaning python bytes from ASCII codes

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, ascii

I'm working with twitter data that are compressed in `.gz` file. As a social media, tweets might have some uncommon characters that when being converted to string, they're shown with codes such as `\u2019, \u201d` and etc. I have been trying different methods to escape these ASCII codes, but none is much working fine.

For example, consider this string:

```
tweet = 'The students who say”Enough is Enough” Grateful to the next'
```

When I encode this bytes to utf-8, which gives me another bytes, I get the following:

```
tweet.encode("utf-8")
>> b'The students who say\xe2\x80\x9dEnough is Enough\xe2\x80\x9d Grateful to the next'
```

Now when I try ignoring ASCII codes and converting the bytes to string, I get:

```
tweet['text'].encode("utf-8").decode("ascii", errors="ignore")
>> 'The students who sayEnough is Enough Grateful to the next'
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to substitute these codes with their correct symbol. For instance, from what I see, it appears that `\u201d` is the code for double quotation mark, but when ignoring this code, this mark gets deleted from the string which is not what I want. The same happens for `\u2019` which the common-sense says it is the code for single quotation mark.

---

**Update:**

At some point, I need to store the tweets into a text file. When I'm not doing any ASCII ignorance, things get really messy. For example, in my text file, I have lots of tweets with strange codes such as `\u2019d`, `\u2026`, `\ud83d` and etc that I don't have any sense of what they are. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Those are just utf-8 encodings of characters that are not in the ascii character set and will be common for any non-English tweet and anybody who uses emojis. If they are stored in a utf-8 encoded text file and later read by something that converts them back to strings, who cares? If you are on windows, you may want to store in `utf-16le` which is the default used by notepad.

Comment: @tdelaney I got this solved by a similar thread. Actually, the whole idea is not just reading and storing from/to file. I need to kind of unify all the tweets and make them suitable for another stage in my programming pipeline. Thanks for the suggestion.